# ubuntu 14.04 won't reboot after standard update

Tags: 14.04

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 on my media centre. I have had no issues to date and regularly update with the standard upgrades. This morning I ran the standard update and was asked to restart computer after completion. Once I did the ubuntu screen had shrunk with the icons oversized. I turned off the computer and then turned it Back on. The computer boots but I'm left with a solid purple screen.

Comment: Try a reboot into your old kernel. That should be enlightening, if it works. You might have to rebuild dkms or something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the Video Drivers.

Enter recovery mode.
Log in with your user name and password.
Install the video drivers for your computer.
If you don't know how to install your video dirvers, follow [this guide.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto)

Comment: The above answer is from here http://askubuntu.com/questions/128574/clean-install-shows-only-purple-screen